# ts-toolbelt giving errors on node_modules. Type alias 'MergeList' circularly references itself

Tags: angular, typescript, vue.js, eslint

I have created a Vue JS app (`vue create <app-name>`) a few months ago and after changing computers I started to get the following errors

```
ERROR in /home/bruno/code/vuejs/rockygym-frontnend/node_modules/ts-toolbelt/out/index.d.ts(4111,10):
4111:10 Type alias 'MergeList' circularly references itself.
    4109 |     @hidden
    4110 |     */
  > 4111 |     type MergeList<O, Path extends List<Key>, O1 extends object, depth extends Depth, I extends Iteration = IterationOf<'0'>> = O extends object ? O extends (infer A)[] ? MergeList<A, Path, O1, depth, I>[] : Pos<I> extends Length<Path> ? OMerge<O, O1, depth> : {
         |          ^
    4112 |         [K in keyof O]: K extends Path[Pos<I>] ? MergeList<O[K], Path, O1, depth, Next<I>> : O[K];
    4113 |     } & {} : O;
    4114 |     /**
```

You can find the full list [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/db19a46f). At fist I thought it was ESLint issue but I tried adding the following entry `.eslintignore`:

```
node_modules
public
bin
build
node_modules/ts-toolbelt/out/index.d.ts
```

But for some reasons I'm still getting the errors when running `vue-cli-service serve --port 1024`. I literally have no idea where to debug from now on. I'm at the point where I'm not looking for a solution right away but at least some guidance on where to look and understand what is causing such errors.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**"
  ],
  "types": [
    "vuetify"
  ]
}
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify',
  ],
  pwa: {
    workboxOptions: {
      skipWaiting: true,
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating ts-toolbelt, solves the problem.

If you are using npm,
`>> npm i ts-toolbelt`

If you are using yarn,
`>> yarn add ts-toolbelt`

Comment: I had some hope when I saw your comment but unfortunately still getting the same error

Comment: This solves the problem in my angular project. I don't know how the status with VueJS projects.